Div height changes after displaying content on hover, when it shouldn't
I have an anchor tag with two children: A fontawesome Icon and a span. The span isn't displayed, until you hover over the anchor.
The issue is that on my website, when the span gets displayed using inline, the parent anchor grows in height. This happens regardless of how big the text is, even when I lower the font-size or line-height of the span.
I've tried isolating the code for the question, but can't replicate the issue. Here it is regardless:


:root {
    --darkblack: #000615;
    --black: #0B1721;
    --lightblack: #141B37;
    --yellow: #F7C921;
    --darkyellow: #a28b2a;
    --cyan: #21B7FF;
    --darkcyan: #1c7eaf;
    --magenta: #FF217D;
    --darkmagenta: #531a3b;
}

.nav {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link {
  width: fit-content;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
   color: var(--black) !important;
   background-color: var(--cyan);
 }

.nav-pills .nav-link:not(.nav-link.active) {
  color: var(--cyan) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link:hover > .nav-title {
  display: inline !important;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-10">
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
            <span class="d-none nav-title">Test</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="nav-link" data-id="tags">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-tags"></i>
            <span class="d-none nav-title">Tags</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
    
  </div>
</div>



I tried going through every single CSS rule for both the span, icon and text to see if disabling any would fix the issue, however the only rule that did was
.fa-classic, .fa-regular, .fa-solid, .far, .fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}

which it gets from the FontAwesome library, and also I can't just replace due to removing it breaking the icon. I can't really seem to find out what could cause this issue. Does anyone have a clue?
Here's a visual of the issue on my site:


Not happening as you're showing in Safari, MacOS. Also not happening on Chrome, MacOS.

Btw, your usage of <title class="d-none nav-title">Tags</title> makes your HTML invalid. You can only have this tag in the  head where it's mandatory, and only once.

HTML also doesn't have  column and row elements. How did you come up with those?

@connexo Bootstrap. If you check out the code example you'll see the include. I've added the tag

Bootstrap is suggesting non-existing HTML tags? Please provide a link.

@connexo sorry ive changed the tags, not that it changed anything about the result

the parent anchor grows in height - no it doesn't.

@Akshay No. We don't need a link to a website. The issue must be reproduced HERE and currently it is not reproducible.

Reading comprehension zero

changing height is not happening for me but you can define height for that to prevent changing height with changing context of element
for example
.nav-link{
           height: 25px; 
          /* other rules */
         }

